# symfony routing, use value from Request as default

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I've got the following route definition

```
my_route:
    path:               /actual-path/
    defaults:
        _controller:    MyBundle:MyController:detail
        id:             application_id
    requirements:
        methods:        GET
        id:             \d+
```

The controller requires a parameter called `$id`.

But I don't want to use the `$id` in the url, I want to use a value that is available in `$request->attributes->get('application_id')`

There is a listener that will inject two parameters (`application_id` and `application`) into the request object as attributes prior to the routing process, so this value is in there. (It would be easy to also inject it into the `RequestContext`).

Is there a way I can use attributes values from the `Request` or `RequestContext` object in my routing as defaults?

---

Now I could simply do `$request->attributes->get('application_id')` in my controller. But this controller will be used in several cases. In other cases the `$id` is to be passed through the url. I find it cleaner to set the id in the routing than build a if-else clause in the controller somewhere.

Comment: Controller::myAction(Request $request, $application_id) will do what you want.  The controller resolver will use the argument names to automatically pull data out of the request object.  Your question is a bit confusing. If the id is not present in the url then just have your listener add in the application_id.  In any event, I suspect your route definition will need a bit more work.

Comment: Thing is, I can't change the controller:action, as that is a generic action (located in the vendor dir). So the controller is expecting `id`, but the value in Request is `application_id`. So basically, I would need some kind of mapping in the routing configuration.

Comment: I suppose you might be able to do it with expressions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#completely-customized-route-matching-with-conditions.  Otherwise, add another kernel listener to do it.

Comment: I was looking into that already, but I'm afraid that would also become a bit of a mess. I guess my best chance is to handle it is to extend the controller and handle it there. If the id === null for instance, use the application_id for instance.

Comment: Listeners are easy especially if you have more than one route with this sort of thing.

Comment: I find listeners quite expensive because they take time on each request. So I try to avoid Request and Response listeners because of that. Unless it really makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It appears not to be possible to do "mapping" between variables in the request object and the parameters you need to be required in your route/controller-action. I think this would be a good thing, as it would become quite complex otherwise.

I went with the solution to extend the controller and build in a small switch there.

Basically, if the route specifies `id === null`, it will do a fallback to `application_id` that is in the Request object. Otherwise it will use the value provided. I just need to set a requirement on id on the routes that must not use the fallback.

All without running an additional Listener which might be a bit "expensive" in processing time (for each request).

Example of routes:

```
my_route:
    path:               /actual-path/
    defaults:
        _controller:    MyBundle:MyController:detail
        id:             null
    requirements:
        methods:        GET

my_other_route:
    path:               /other-path/{id}
    defaults:
        _controller:    MyBundle:MyController:detail
    requirements:
        methods:        GET
        id:             \d+
```

And how to handle this in your controller:

```
    // fallback to system id
    if ($id === null) {
        $id = $request->attributes->get('administration_id', null);
    }
```

Because you extend the controller/action, you could also change the name of the parameter in the action (as long as the type does not change).

I did not do this, as I could quite easily put the switch between the provided id and the fallback from the listener in another method.

Comment: Just be aware that you could use your existing listener for this.  A subscriber can listen to different events at different times.  But whatever works for you is fine.